# Скриншот сайта по размерам Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Делаю скриншот сайта при помощи `Selenium`.
Задаю размеры скриншота - `1280x1280`. Но штука в том, что он делает скрин во всю высоту сайта, а не чётко ту, которую я задал. Про всю высоту имею ввиду то что есть скролл.

Как быть?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно JavaDoc API для интерфейса [TakesScreenshot](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html), WebDriver реализующий TakesScreenshot, приложит максимальное усилие, чтобы возвратить следующее в порядке предпочтения:

- Вся страница
- Текущее окно
- Видимая часть текущей структуры
- Скриншот всего показа, содержащего браузер

Поскольку PhantomJS - headless браузер, у него, вероятно, нет меню/вкладок и другого подобного хрома элементов браузера. Таким образом, все, чем Вы можете управлять, являются размеры окна браузера.

```
// Portrait iPhone 6 browser dimensions
Dimension dim = new Dimension(375, 627);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
```

Создание скриншота скорее всего захватит всю страницу. Если Вы хотите ограничить скриншот заданными размерами, которые вы просили, вы могли бы всегда [обрезать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894275/loading-cropping-saving-an-image-in-java) его до нужных размерам (не идеально, но PhantomJS не реальный браузер).

```
 private static void capture(String url, WebDriver driver, Dimension dim, String filename) throws IOException{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
    driver.get(url);
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    int w = dim.getWidth();
    int h = dim.getHeight();
    Image orig = ImageIO.read(scrFile);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bi.getGraphics().drawImage(orig, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(filename));
  }
```